# Can I claim if Customs open & damage my parcel even though contents clearly labelled & nothing was found

Tags: united-kingdom, search-and-seizure, customs-law

A model train was sent from Canada to UK & clearly marked. It took a year to make & was then sold. It has been drilled by customs from bottom to top & the buyer no longer wants it. He was charged £101 when delivered for the pleasure of having his train ruined.
Can I claim compensation?

Answer (score 2):

You may be entitled to compensation [according to HMRC](https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/complaints-and-remedy-guidance/crg5600). The page gives addresses to send complaints to.